# How to show that Kneser graphs are $\binom{n - k}{k}$-regular

Tags: graph-theory

I am tasked to prove that any [Kneser graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph) $G_{n, k}$ is $\binom{n - k}{k}$-regular.

Compared to the trivial proof that a Kneser graph's order is $\binom{n}{k}$, this has been much more difficult for me, as it is not immediately obvious how the every set in the powerset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ will always lack shared elements with exactly $\binom{n - k}{k}$ other sets. I have observed examples from $G_{6, 1}$ and $G_{5, 2}$, in which each vertex is of degree $4$ and $3$, respectively, but the logic behind this is still unclear to me.
How can I go about investigating this?

Comment: Once you fix a vertex (a $k$-subset) you are left with $n-k$ elements that can appear within any adjacent vertex.Or, if you like, in $G_{n,k}$ the neibhood of any vertex is isomorphic to $G_{n-k,k}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a subset $A \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}$ of $k$ elements (representing a vertex), our goal is to determine the number of sets $B$, also consisting of $k$ elements from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, that are disjoint from $A$ (i.e., that is, see when vertices connect with A).

To construct set $B$, it's crucial to note that we cannot use the $k$ elements from $A$. Consequently, with $n-k$ elements remaining, we aim to form a set of $k$ elements. In total, the count of such sets is $\binom{n-k}{k}$.